# Libgdx sequencing and delays

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm working on a java project for uni and we've had to adopt another groups code and work with that instead. Having not used Libgdx I'm pretty confused.

The idea behind it is to set the text to something, have it fade out after a small amount of time and then set the text to something else, however java obviously ignores any delays as it reads the code so it changes the text immediately instead of waiting for the delay and fade.

I'm pretty new to java and as I said I don't have a massive understanding of Libgdx, but here's the code anyway:

```
public void displayFlashMessage(String message, Color color, float time) {
    flashMessage.clearActions();
    flashMessage.setText(message);
    flashMessage.setColor(color);
    flashMessage.setPosition(TaxeGame.WORLD_WIDTH / 2 - flashMessage.getTextBounds().width / 2, TaxeGame.WORLD_HEIGHT - 24);
    flashMessage.addAction(sequence(delay(time), fadeOut(0.25f)));
    flashMessage.setText("ASD");

}
```

(I have used "ASD" as an example string here. flashmessage is of type Label)

Answer (score 0):

You should perform last text change in the action sequence as well.

```
flashMessage.addAction(sequence(delay(time), fadeOut(0.25f), run(new Runnable() {
    public void run () {
        flashMessage.setText("ASD");
    }
})));
```

Fore reference, you can follow [**Scene2d action completion**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#action-completion).